# Hiding SuperSU and Kingo Root

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to hide the root and superSU icons from the android devices. My Company wants to hide them to keep our app tidy without having all those extra icons on our phones.

I've tried shelling

```
 pm hide com.kingoroot.com
 pm hide com.kingouser.com
```

but the icons remain, also tried rebooting after but same result.

Comment: A company with rooted phones? Very strange. Is the rooted access really needed?

Comment: yes, had to create a binder app between two applications with logic in order to keep our stock levels correct, what comes in is not what goes out. the companies that created said applications could not create the logic correctly due to the variables involved with the products.

Comment: did you try pm disable com.kingoroot.com

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly straight-forward:

`adb shell pm hide "package.name"`

EX:

`adb shell pm hide "com.jondouglas.application"`

After it kicks in, you should see:

`Package com.jondouglas.application new hidden state: true`

After about 5-10 seconds, the icon will disappear from any screens.